# Protractor test timing out waiting for page sync

Tags: angularjs, integration-testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

My protractor tests are timing out waiting for page sync. I've checked the console, and no errors are shown, so I'm having trouble debugging. I've tried using allScriptsTimeout as well as defaultTimeoutInterval to no avail. No polling in my app, and the test does seem to log in correctly, it just hangs once logged in even though everything looks fully rendered. My code:

Config file:

```
var exports;
exports.config = {
// The address of a running selenium server.
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',    

// Spec patterns are relative to the location of this config.
specs: [
    'scenarios/features/portfolio-manager-e2e-local.js'
],

multiCapabilities: [
    {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    }
],

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 20000,
}
};
```

Test:

I'll just post one for now, the first test that runs and fails:

```
it('should login user with correct credentials', function () {
    browser.get('/#/portfolio');
    element(by.model('username')).sendKeys('test');
    element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('test');
    element(by.css('.btn.btn-md.btn-primary')).click();
    expect(element(by.css('.port-header')).getText()).toEqual("Portfolios");
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to get the test passing after I cranked     allScriptsTimeout up 20000, but this seems like a slow and inefficient means of testing. Does this mean one of my $http is taking almost 20 seconds to be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an ngToast successful login popup had a timeout of 15.5 seconds which was causing the hangup.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, has `waitForAngular()` helped to overcome the `ngToast` timeout?

Comment: I actually didn't try, I just removed the ngToast popup, which I didn't want anyways. Does waitForAngular() supersede the defaultTimeoutInterval? If so, this probably would have worked as well.

Comment: `waitForAngular` basically listens for the event from angular being fired saying that "okay, guys, I'm done taking part in this page's load" :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [wait for angular](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.waitForAngular) before making any assertions:

> Instruct webdriver to wait until Angular has finished rendering and
>   has no outstanding $http calls before continuing.

```
browser.get('/#/portfolio');
browser.waitForAngular()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found out that an ngToast popup had a timeout of 15.5 seconds which was causing the hangup.